# Div not allowed Validation Error

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I use the following PHP code to generate some JS and echo it in my page

```
$var_x = $var_x . "var_array[$var_count] = '<div class=\"var_div\"></div>'; ";
```

However, when I try to validate it with the W3C validator, I get the following error.

```
'document type does not allow element "div" here'
```

The error highlights the > at the end of the  tag

What could be the problem?

Comment: paste the HTML you finally generate here. I'm assuming you're getting error in JS and not in PHP right?

Comment: Yes in the JS.
var_array[0] = '<div class=\'var_div\'></div>';

Comment: I don't think the error is in this piece of code. It's valid. You might want to use Firebug or something to step through your code. Or paste the relevant bits here so someone can go through it.

Comment: It operates exactly right, and it all seems valid to me as well, but I am just trying to get the w3c validator to agree. I get the same error for each item in the array.

Comment: Oh, you mean W3C validator? You need to put it inside a CDATA section I think. That should fix it.

Comment: Thank you, John! Never used that before and it did the trick. You saved me hours of no sleep.

Comment: been working with php for about 15-18 years. The dual semicolons at the end won't work... The one outside the double quotes is right. typically, and I cannot see what you are doing with the rest of your php coding, a line of php code would end like this `...</div>' ";` Looks like you are trying to use php, to output java, without breaking out of php with a close `?>` tag and a new open tag every line you iterate as you pass through your array.
Sometimes you have to steout of php, to put in the offending character, your semicolon and use the `<? ?>` where the variables change as you read them o

Comment: no problem. Added it as an answer for people with the same question.

Comment: Ummm, is that a typo? 15 - 18 years?! In any case, the PHP syntax is not at fault here. Neither is the resulting JS. This is just a matter of XHTML validation.

Comment: no. not at all. all my sites have parsed perfect xhtml for years. sorry I offered the thing that will fix it. I have done this a few hundred times... over the years. the double semis within the php code will never parse xhtml at output. you have to step out of it, php can repeat the non php items as well as the code. enjoy attacking folks tonight okay...

Comment: I apologize if my comment seemed offensive to you, I was just a bit nonplussed. But again, the PHP isn't invalid. The first semi colon is actually inside the quotes so there's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: Sorry Mak, JohnP is right here. The semi-colon inside the quotes is to terminate the JS statement -- has nothing to do with PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the XHTML [CDATA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA) section to denote areas where you may be working with HTML. This will let the validator know that it needs to ignore the contents and not try to parse it.

Comment: I don't get why the validator would try to parse what is presumably inside a `<script>` block?

Comment: It just looks inside the `<script>` tag and then sees the `<` and `>` and starts to parse it. You usually have to use it within the style and script tags so the validator doesn't choke on them - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA#Use_of_CDATA_in_program_output

Comment: @Mark There is a difference between XHTML and HTML here! In HTML, the contents of a <script> are defined as CDATA automatically. Not so in XHTML, so you should explicitly specify a CDATA block yourself. You are using a XHTML doctype declaration, right? If you were to change it to a HTML one, the error would go away.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this will error out, because you are trying to build html document element inside javascript.

If you echo php variable `$var_x` in the javascript, it will write your string into document and  your string contains document element and when HTML try to parse your html and javascript it will error out.

Comment: That wasn't the issue. The 'error' was actually an error in xHTML validation